# Understanding RAM's Burst Mode

Tags: memory

I was reading [this article](https://computer.howstuffworks.com/computer-memory3.htm) and got confused when I came across this paragraph describing burst mode:

> Burst mode depends on the expectation that data requested by the CPU
> will be stored in sequential memory cells. The memory controller
> anticipates that whatever the CPU is working on will continue to come
> from this same series of memory addresses, so it reads several
> consecutive bits of data together. This means that only the first bit
> is subject to the full effect of latency; reading successive bits
> takes significantly less time. The rated burst mode of memory is
> normally expressed as four numbers separated by dashes. The first
> number tells you the number of clock cycles needed to begin a read
> operation; the second, third and fourth numbers tell you how many
> cycles are needed to read each consecutive bit in the row, also known
> as the wordline. For example: 5-1-1-1 tells you that it takes five
> cycles to read the first bit and one cycle for each bit after that.
> Obviously, the lower these numbers are, the better the performance of
> the memory.

How does this work? How does it offset latency? How does RAM normally access information and how does this compare to burst mode?

Comment: The quote you pasted literally answers every single one of your questions. For example, "How does this work?" is answered by "The memory controller anticipates that whatever the CPU is working on will continue to come from this same series of memory addresses, so it reads several consecutive bits of data together.". And so on.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz alright. I don't understand what is written in quote I copy pasted. Would breaking the quote down to explain what parts I did and did not understand make my answer better?

Comment: Yes--it would help.

Answer (score 1):

The difference comes from that, for the first random access, you will have to tell the memory chip the address. The address is typically given in two parts, the row and column addresses separately. This requires time for signals to settle on both the controller and RAM side. The consecutive bits you just have to clock in; the RAM chip keeps an internal address counter that is incremented after each read or write.

However, most of the speed advantage comes from the fact that the RAM chip internally fetches a whole row into a buffer internal to the chip. The row access is slow, but consecutive bits in the same row can be quickly transferred from this row buffer.